# Django: How to implement JOIN using Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, foreign-keys

user_key, geo_key [30/Sep/2019 10:31:13] "POST /user/geog_user_mapping HTTP/1.1" 500 142108

Comment: Can you tell in a statement what data you want like `I want all users with geokey 7`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
User_Mapping.objects.filter(user_key_id=request.data['user_key']).select_related('geo_key')
```

Django automatically appends `_id` to any `FK` column.

**Note** that `select_related` is only a performance booster.  You can access foreign table columns without it, like this:

```
user_map = User_Mapping.objects.filter(user_key_id=request.data['user_key'])
user_map[0].geography.zone

print(list(user_map))
```

Comment: @PriyanshiSingh can you update with the full traceback for the error you get after trying my code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
 <title>FieldError
  at /user/geog_user_mapping

Comment: Hi @PriyanshiSingh, the traceback should look like this http://dpaste.com/1ZN7VKP

Comment: File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 940, in get_related_selections
    ', '.join(_get_field_choices()) or '(none)',
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'geography'. Choices are: user_key, geo_key
[30/Sep/2019 10:31:13] "POST /user/geog_user_mapping HTTP/1.1" 500 142108

Comment: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'geography'. Choices are: user_key, geo_key [30/Sep/2019 10:31:13] "POST /user/geog_user_mapping HTTP/1.1" 500

Comment: @PriyanshiSingh Sorry, you need to use `geo_key` instead of `geography`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Do I need to serialize it to get the output?

Comment: I was wondering if I can fetch all the fields from views.py itself without serialising it, as I haven't worked on getting data from 2 different serializers

Comment: Uh, no?  I'm guessing you tried to print them and say something like `<QuerySet <[...]>`.  Is that what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the tables. It's just because you're trying to access to `user_key` on a `dict` that might not work when that `dict` doesn't contain the `user_key` attribute.

On your code, `request.data` is a dictionary which doesn't have `user_key` attribute. It should be access via `keyword` instead of `attribute`, that mean `request.data['user_key']` will works

Try this instead:

```py
User_Mapping.objects.all().select_related('geography').filter(user_key=request.data.get('user_key'))
```

**EDIT:**

After some discussion `request.data.get('user_key')` might return a user id instead of user object so you can filter by `user_key_id` instead. Like so:

```py
User_Mapping.objects.all().select_related('geography').filter(user_key_id=request.data.get('user_key'))
```

Comment: This won't work because `user_key` is a `ForeignKey` column, and django appends `_id` to these columns.  If you use `user_key` as a filter, django is expecting a `User` object, and not a `pk`.

Comment: How if request.data.get('user_key') returned a User instance? The point here is the error she's facing with. Maybe that `user_key` is an id but whatever, that has nothing to do with her error message right? If it is an id then she will receive another error soon and that will be a different story

Answer (score 0):

First, get the user Object like:

```
user_object= User.objects.filter(id=request.data.user_key).first()
```

Your queries should be like:

```
User_Mapping.objects.filter(user_key=user_object).select_related('geo_key')

Geography.objects.filter(user_mapping__user_key=user_key)

User_Mapping.objects.filter(user_key=3).select_related('any_model_filed_name')
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: This won't work.  See my comment on Toan's answer for an explanation.

Comment: I have Updated answer.

Comment: This won't work. See my answer below for an explanation

Comment: Updated answer!